# sh script with scp variables

Tags: cygwin, sh, scp

I am trying to writing a simple script which will figure out the latest version of a file by the filename and then download that file to the local computer.

What I cant figure out is why my code will work in the shell, but not work when I run it as a script.  I am also running my script on cygwin, not sure if that will make a difference.

Here is the script

```
#!/bin/sh
x=$(ssh user@hostname 'ls -r -t /vgf/day1*.gif | tail -1')
echo $x
scp user@hostname:"${x}" /images/day1.gif
```

x is correctly assigned, but when I get to the scp command I receive something along the lines of

```
: No such file or directoryif
```

However if I run the scp command in the shell it will work

```
$ sh download.sh
/vgf/day1.gif
: No such file or directoryif
$ scp user@hostname:"${x}" /images/day1.gif
day1.gif                                              100%   22KB  22.1KB/s   00:00
```

I would be open to different solutions.  If I could prevent the version increasing via some linux administration, I may follow that route, although I am still wondering what the problem is here.

By version, I mean day1_001.gif and the new version becoming day1_002.gif and so on.  So when the file saves a file day1.gif, it will overwrite the original without creating another version.

Comment: Run your script with -x option, you can `set -x` to have a trace of problem area in code.  That error message is a standard one, you probably have a variable undefined as it's a shell variable (not evironmental) or quoting problems or tricky filenames.  But I'm afraid, file access with shells in face of awkward names are hard to get right.  It's one reason why sysadmins moved to perl or python.  For shadowing trees of files, you ought check out rsync, it can use the ssh shell for remote access, and has many features for showing changed files, which may make convenient lists for your scripts

Comment: Ah, cygwin. I can't remember if cygwin uses `\r\n` endings or not. Easy to check with `dos2unix myScpScript`. This may solve your problem immediately, and it can't hurt your script otherwise. Good luck!